# How to remove an Array Key From an Array_Chunck?

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, unset

I have `array_chunk` a set of 10 keys within each array that loops through. I want to remove the key [10]=> from each array that is looped so I will have 9 keys remaining. What I have so far.

```
    $page = array( "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s");

$number_of_pages_to_copy = 5;

$x = 1;

    while($x <= $number_of_pages_to_copy) { 


      $sum = array_chunk($page, 11);
      unset($sum['10']);
      print_r($sum);

    $x++;
    }
```

Current output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => "a" [2] => "b" [3] => "c" [4] => "d" [5] => "e" [6] => "f" [7] => "g" [8] => "h" [9] => "i" [10]=> "j" )

[1]=> Array ( [1] => "a" [2] => "b" [3] => "c" [4] => "d" [5] => "e" [6] => "f" [7] => "g" [8] => "h" [9] => "i" [10]=> "j" )
```

Desired output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => "a" [2] => "b" [3] => "c" [4] => "d" [5] => "e" [6] => "f" [7] => "g" [8] => "h" [9] => "i" )

[1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => "a" [2] => "b" [3] => "c" [4] => "d" [5] => "e" [6] => "f" [7] => "g" [8] => "h" [9] => "i" )
```

Nothing is happening, The unset seems not to be working.

Comment: If you want to remove the last element, have you tried [array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)? In any case, $sum is originally 11 keys long, not 10.

Comment: You can do `$sum = array_values(array_chunk($page, 11));` to get a fresh index from 0-x, and indexes are not used as string do `unset($sum[10]);`

Comment: I tried array_pop, didn't work as well.

Comment: Plz update your Q with $page output, your actual ouput result and what you expect.

Comment: $sum = array_values(array_chunk($page, 11)); isn't removing [10]=>

Comment: Show output of all....  `isn't removing` `dont't work` does not help

Comment: And this `$sum = array_values(array_chunk($page, 11));` is reindexing the array, not removing anything. Plz eat some logic :)

Comment: you $sum is an array of array, you need $sum[0][10] to get the value you want

Comment: Tried unset($sum[0][10]), the key did remove but it's value remains now along side [9]=>

Comment: How about taking time to learn php before running into the wild ;) Tip:`error_reporting(E_ALL);` and php.net

Comment: I've been doing PhP for years, I'm not a novice. By the way your array_value answer doesn't work. I tried that hours ago before even asking this question. I don't have errors, the logic is just screwy

Answer (score 0):

Your $sum is an array of array,  so you have to use another index or foreach.

```
  array_slice($sum[0],0,10);
```

or

```
foreach($sum as &$v)
{
  unset($v[10]);
}
```

for you unset the last index of the array, so you neednot to reindex the array, if not use array_values after unset.

Here is a demo:

```
<?php
$page = array( "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s");
$arrays= array_chunk($page, 11);
foreach($arrays as &$array)
{
    unset($array[10]);
}
print_r($arrays);
```

output:

```
ei@localhost:~$ php test.php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
            [4] => e
            [5] => f
            [6] => g
            [7] => h
            [8] => i
            [9] => j
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => l
            [1] => m
            [2] => n
            [3] => o
            [4] => p
            [5] => q
            [6] => r
            [7] => s
        )

)
```

or

```
<?php
$page = array( "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s");
$arrays= array_chunk($page, 11);
$arrays = array_map(function($v){return array_slice($v, 0, 10);}, $arrays);
print_r($arrays);
```

and this will get the same output.

Comment: Your statment isnt right. unset does what unset does and dont need array_values. if the user wants to reindex the array after unsetting something array_values comes in play. How does your answer work with assoc-arrays? `$a=array('a'=>'a','b'=>'b'); unset($a['b']); print_r(array_values($a));`??

Comment: `var_dump` what? What did you use for testing your code?  And `array_values[$sum]` should be `array_values($sum);`.   im leaving.......

Comment: I used unset($sum[0][10]), the key is gone but it's values still remain now along side [9]=>

Comment: try the foreach with reference

Comment: the foreach loop gives a warning error:Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Tried array_slice same result as unset with your example. It would be fine if only [1] => Array ( [0] => comes after [9]=> in the same array_chuck.